# Gradle error with GmailSender Integration

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, jakarta-mail, email

I'm trying to integrate this [project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124) to mine.

I have imported all the jar. I can Rebuild the project without an error. But when I try to install the app on my Phone, while the Gradle Builds, 280 errors appears. At the end I've got the message BUILD SUCCESSFUL and the app is running normally on the Phone (even if I don't receive my mail, but it's an other problem).

This is what my Gradle Console shows :

```
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses     attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder$13) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder$10) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
```

and much more !

But when I delete the sendmail() method in my activity, the errors disappear.

I hope that someone can help me, thank you in advance.

Sorry if I have made some English mistakes.

EDIT: an update of the JavaMail Package fix my problem.

Comment: The project you're using is pretty old.  You might want to try the official version of [JavaMail for Android](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#JavaMail_for_Android).

Comment: @BillShannon I've updated the package with yours and it fix my problem. Thank you.